# Determine if 2 UNC paths on the same remote machine are on the same volume

Tags: c#, unc, driveinfo

I am working on a service that has special conditions if the two UNC paths given to it reside on the same volume. However I have yet to figure out a way of determining this since the C# DriveInfo class does not work with UNC paths.

EX:

\\server\path_a resides on drive A

\\server\path_b resides on drive B

Is there some way of telling that \\server\path_a and \\server\path_b do not reside on the same drive remotely?

Comment: AFAIK  this  not possible

Comment: I agree with @Julie - it's either not possible or not reliable. How would you handle the case when `\\server\path_a` and `\\192.168.12.12\path_a` point to the same folder?

Comment: You might get close with [Active directory to tell something like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C). Might not be exactly what you want tho.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ i would use netenum share to get the remote physical path and then check if they are on the same path. You could probably to the same in c#

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but you will need to use PInvoke to call into a WinAPI interface located in the NetAPI32 library. For example:

Depending on your needs you can get the SHARE_INFO_2 struct for the shares by calling [NetShareGetInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525388(v=vs.85).aspx), which will give you that info object for the share. Have a look at the struct [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525408(v=vs.85).aspx). The *shi2_path* property will give you the local path which contains the drive.

The MSDN documentation states the following about that property:

> **shi2_path**
>
> Pointer to a Unicode string specifying the local path for
> the shared resource. For disks, shi2_path is the path being shared.

**Please Note:** *You will need to have sufficient credentials to get the SHARE_INFO_2 object.*

Then when you get both paths you can do something like (very rudimentary):

```
bool isDriveEqual = sharePath1[0] == sharePath2[0];
```